# Evaluating the sum of $kl^2$ over $p,q,k,l$ such that $pk +ql = n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-functions, ramanujan

I have come across the following sum:

$$\sum_{\substack{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \\ k > l \\ pk + ql = n}}kl^2$$

and I am trying to simplify it, hoping to get a nice formula in terms of $n$ and some arithmetic functions of $n$.

For instance, the following sum can be evaluated as follows:

\begin{align*}
 \sum_{\substack{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \\ pk + ql = n}}kl &= \sum_{\substack{\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}\\ \alpha+ \beta = n}}\sum_{k | \alpha}k \sum_{l | \beta}l \\ 
&= \sum_{\substack{\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{N}\\ \alpha+ \beta = n}} \sigma_1(\alpha) \sigma_1(\beta)\\
&= (\sigma_1 \Delta \sigma_1)(n)
\end{align*}
where $\sigma_1(n)$ is the sum of divisors of $n$ and $\Delta$ is the discrete convolution. 
Ramanujan has a formula for the discrete convolution of $\sigma_1$ with itself given by
$$(\sigma_1 \Delta \sigma_1)(n) = \frac{5}{12}\sigma_3(n) + \frac{1}{12}\sigma_1(n) - \frac{1}{2} n \sigma_1(n)$$
where $\sigma_3(n)$ is the sum of the cubes of the divisors of $n$.

Any thoughts on how one might proceed with the sum in the beginning of the question? The asymmetry between $k$ and $l$ is causing some problems so the same approach as for the second sum does not quite work.

I would be very much grateful for any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there even a closed form for sum of $k^2 l^2?$

Comment: (nice question, by the way)

Comment: If you change the title to something more descriptive, you'll probably get a better response.

Comment: Can you give more backgraund concerning your question? Do you need exactly this sum or sum with additional restrictions on $p,q,k,l$?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov For this case, I needed this exact sum. It comes up while counting square tiled surfaces.

Comment: Can you explain this poblem (on square tiled surfaces) in more details?

Comment: A reference I can give: https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~lelievre/papers/LeRo1/LeRo1_2up.pdf by Lelievre and Royer

Answer (score 5):

Using elementary methods, for p,q,k,l strictly positive, I find :
$\frac{1}{24}\sigma_4(n) + \frac{1}{2}\sigma_3(n) - \frac{1}{24} (12n+1)\sigma_2(n)$

The asymmetry is not a problem if you replace $k$ with $k+l$, which is greater than $l$.

**Edit**: Sorry @alex-m, you're right, I'll try to summarize.

The idea is first to use the Dirichlet transform of the summand; 
If we have to sum $f(n)$ from 1 to infinity we consider $\sum {\frac {f(n)}{n^s}}$ with $s$ real but large enough for the sum to converge.
Then if we can show that $\sum {\frac {f(n)}{n^s}}$ is equal to some other transform $\sum {\frac {g(n)}{n^s}}$ for all $s$ large enough, it is not difficult to prove that $f(n)=g(n)$ for all $n$.
Typically here we'll use the well-known Dirichlet transform $\sum {\frac {\sigma_a(n)}{n^s}} = \zeta(s) \zeta(s-a)$ and we'll seek a way to transform the wanted original Dirichlet sum into a combination of such known sums.

Here the wanted $f(n)$ is $\sum_{\substack{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \\ k > l \\ pk + ql = n}}k l^2$
As I said the $k>l$ specification can be ignored if the sum becomes $\sum_{\substack{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \\ p(k+l) + ql = n}}(k+l)l^2$
The Dirichlet transform $\sum {\frac {f(n)}{n^s}}$ to consider will be simply $\sum_{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N}} \frac {(k+l)l^2} {(p(k+l) + ql)^s}$

The next step consists in finding an approaching sum, which can be transformed in at least two different ways, bringing the desired sum.
Here this approaching sum will be $ A(s) = \sum_{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N}} \frac {k l^2} {(pk + ql)^s}$

I recall that $s$ will be large enough for all the considered sums to converge.
We use a "diagonalization" scheme to transform $A(s)$ in two ways; since we have multiple indices, we split the sum in three parts :
$ \sum_{a,b >0} h(a,b) = \sum_{a>0} h(a,a) + \sum_{a,b >0} h(a+b,b) + \sum_{a,b >0} h(a,b+a)$

Here we "diagonalize" $A(s)$ first over $k$ and $l$, and second over $p$ and $q$.
In the process we  get the desired $\sum_{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N}} \frac {(k+l)l^2} {(p(k+l) + ql)^s}$ and other sums easy to manage, which I don't detail but bring the $\zeta(s)$ function.
At the end we get the desired result for $f(n)$.

Comment: The OP is trying to simplify a sum, and is looking for suggestions about how to do this. You only provide a closed-form result, instead of an approach; in particular, we have no way of checking whether your result is correct, if you do not provide us with its proof.

Comment: @AlexM.: At least numerically, the two expressions match for all $n<100$. I'd be very surprised if they are not equal.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev: Agreed, but I believe that the OP was looking not just for a closed-form result, but rather for a *method* of obtaining it. Notice that the initial version of this answer (that my comment addressed) was very brief, containing only the part above the later edit; in the meantime, its author has siginificantly improved it, rendering my initial comment somewhat useless. The answer as it stands now is very good.

Comment: Thank you @rosab.

Most of this is very new to me so I will take some time to digest this.

For beginners, what are the $h(a, b)$ functions?

Comment: @metallicmural99 The line you refer to is here to explain a general fact: if you sum an infinite number of positive terms $h(a,b)$ (without convergence concerns) using two indices $a$ and $b$ each varying from 1 to infinity, you may split the summation into three parts: $a=b$ (the "diagonal"), $a>b$ and $a<b$. Next I apply that to $A(s) = \sum_{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N}} \frac {k l^2} {(pk + ql)^s}$ with $a=k$ and $b=l$, and also with $a=p$ and $b=q$. The resulting partial summations have to be considered separately. Sorry I didn't detail everything.

Comment: @rosab Ah ok. Thank you for explaining! That makes a lot of sense. Sorry I'm new to evaluating sums such as these and asking naive questions.

Answer (score 3):

Sums of this type can be calculated using standard tools from analytic number theory (Kloosterman sums + Poisson summation). This sum with additional restrictions arose in Frobenius problem. For precise statement see Lemma 8 (page 828) in the article [On the Frobenius problem for three arguments](http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1070/SM8370/meta) (2016) by  I. Vorob'ev.

In my earlier work [The solution of Arnold's problem on the weak asymptotics of Frobenius numbers with three arguments](http://iam.khv.ru/articles/Ustinov/nth27_eng.pdf) (2009) the same tools used for calculation of more simple sums
$$\sum_{\substack{p, q, k, l \in \mathbb{N} \\ pk + ql = n\\\text{+additional restrictions}}}k $$
but this technique allows to replace the summand $k$ by more or less arbitrary smooth function of $p,q,k,l.$

If you need sharper error terms then you should apply more advanced tools like cancellation of Kloosterman sums, Kuznetsov trace formula and averaging over spectrum of Laplace operator from [An Additive Divisor Problem](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1112/jlms/s2-26.1.1/full) by J. M. Deshouillers and H. Iwaniec.

Comment: It seems they want money in exchange for the article...

Comment: @PietroMajer Yes, but you can download it via https://sci-hub.tw/ for free.

Comment: The referenced results (including Lemma 8) are asymptotic, aren't they? But OP asks for an exact expression, as I understand.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Yes, this results are asymptotic. OP din't ask for exact expression, just for nice formula. And existence of exact expression is a big question. The error term here is combined from complicated expressions with Kloosterman sums.

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov: Exact expression is given in rosab's answer.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Yes, rosab gave a nice answer. But in all applications I know such sums arise with additional restrictions. That is why I mentioned a tool which will be suitable in a more general situation.

Comment: Anyway, "can be calculated" sounds confusing. I'd rather say "can be estimated" since you talk about asymptotic methods.

Answer (score 2):

This will probably get a real answer soon and this is more of a comment, but as you are describing it, the generating function for sums of the form $k^{2t} l^{2s}$ is the Fourier series of a product of Eisenstein series (the [wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Eisenstein_series) has a lot of identities) so your problem seems to be more the parity than the asymmetry.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I am having trouble deducing the generating functions for the sums of the form $k^{2t}l^{2s}$ from the wikipedia article you linked.

I think I see how to get the ones when $k$ and $l$ have odd exponents, but don't quite get the ones for even exponents..

Comment: I think that the asymmetry mentioned is the $k>l$ inequality, and that seems to be a bit tricky regardless of parity..